# How to load a nested model into a Extjs form using loadRecord

Tags: javascript, dynamic, extjs, extjs4

I've created a script to dynamically generate a form, but I'm having problem loading the data of the nested model.  I've tried loading the whole record and I've tried loading each sub store, but neither works.

I've through about using form.load(), but from my understanding that requires a proxy connection and also require to store json data inside a 'data' array.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how might I approach this problem?

```
    <div id="view-@pageSpecificVar" class="grid-container even"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
<script>

    Ext.define('HeaderForm', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;
            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                id: Ext.id(),
                defaultType: 'textfield'
            });
            me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    // Define our data model
    Ext.define('HeaderModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'HeaderSequence', type: 'int'}
        ],
        hasMany:[
            { name: 'Columns', model: 'ColumnModel' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            actionMethods: { create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST' },
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Test/Header")',
            timeout: 1200000,
        },
    });

    Ext.define('ColumnModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'ColumnWidth', type: 'float'}
        ],
        hasMany:[
            { name: 'Fields', model: 'FieldModel'}
        ],
        belongsTo: 'HeaderModel'
    });

    Ext.define('FieldModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'XType', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'FieldLabel', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'Name', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'Data', type: 'string'},
            { name: 'FieldSpecify', type: 'bool'}
        ],
        belongsTo: 'ColumnModel'
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'HeaderStore',
        model: 'HeaderModel',
        autoDestroy: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function (result, records, successful, eOpts) {
                //console.log(result);
                var form = dynamicForm(records[0]);
                form.add(submitButton);
                form.render('view-@pageSpecificVar');
            }
        }
    });

    store.load();

    var dynamicForm = function(record) {

        var form = new HeaderForm();
        var columnContainer = new Ext.widget({
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'column'
        });
        var formItems = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();

        Ext.each(record.ColumnsStore.data.items, function(item) {

            Ext.iterate(item.data, function (key, value) {


                var fieldContainer = new Ext.widget({
                    xtype: 'container',
                    columnWidth: value
                });

                Ext.each(item.FieldsStore.data.items, function(item) {
                    if(item.data["FieldSpecify"]) {
                        fieldContainer.add(new Ext.widget({
                            xtype: item.data["XType"],
                            fieldLabel: item.data["FieldLabel"],
                            name: item.data["Name"],
                            //value: item.data["Name"]
                        }));
                    }
                }, this);

                columnContainer.add(fieldContainer);

            }, this);

        }, this);

        formItems.add(columnContainer);

        form.add(formItems.items);

        Ext.each(record.ColumnsStore.data.items, function(item) {
            Ext.each(item.FieldsStore.data.items, function(fields) {
                form.loadRecord(fields);
            });
        });

        //form.loadRecord(record);

        return form;
    };

    var submitButton = new Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function(button) {
                var basic = button.up('form').form;
                basic.updateRecord(basic.getRecord());
                var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('HeaderStore');
                store.each(function(record) {
                    record.dirty = true;
                });
                store.sync();
            }
        }]
    });

</script>
```

**Update**
Sorry I probably didn't made it very clear.  I'm having problem loading the store data into form fields.  For static forms I normally use *loadRecord* to load the nested model into a form, but in this case all the fields are nested in their own little model, so would there be a way to load each nested model value into their own field with loadRecord?

The HeaderModel stores field set information.

The purpose of ColumnModel is to create the container that will surround a set of fields, for styling purpose.  It simply creates two columns of fields.

The FieldModel stores the field specific attributes and data.

Here's an example of response json data...

```
{
"HeaderSequence":1,
    "Columns":[{
        "ColumnWidth":0.5,"Fields":[
            {"XType":"textfield","FieldLabel":"FieldA","Name":"NameA","Data":"A","FieldSpecify":true},
            {"XType":"textfield","FieldLabel":"FieldB","Name":"NameA","Data":"B","FieldSpecify":true}]
        },{
        "ColumnWidth":0.5,"Fields":[
            {"XType":"textfield","FieldLabel":"FieldA2","Name":"NameA2","Data":"A2","FieldSpecify":true},
            {"XType":"textfield","FieldLabel":"FieldB2","Name":"NameB2","Data":"B2","FieldSpecify":true}]
        }   
]
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figure out how to load the nested model into the form.  We can't simply use load or loadRecord, as by default that method tries to get a model's data and iterate through the data object and call setValues.

What I have to do is manually get the basic form element and call setValues myself to assign the values.

```
        // loop through each field store to load the data into the form by field id
        Ext.each(record.ColumnsStore.data.items, function(item) {
            Ext.each(item.FieldsStore.data.items, function(fields) {
                form.getForm().setValues([{ id: fields.data['Id'], value: fields.data['DisplayName'] }]);
            });
        });
```

To Follow up with that, a custom submit handler needs to be put in place as well.
Which loops through the store and sets the submitted value to store before sync the store.

```
// define form submit button
    var submitButton = new Ext.widget({
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function(button) {
                // get basic form for button
                var basic = button.up('form').form;
                // get form submit values
                var formSubmitValues = basic.getValues();
                // get header store
                var store = Ext.StoreMgr.get('HeaderStore');
                // loop through each field store and update the data values by id from the form
                store.each(function(record) {
                    Ext.each(record.ColumnsStore.data.items, function(item) {
                        Ext.each(item.FieldsStore.data.items, function(fields) {
                            fields.data['Data'] = formSubmitValues[fields.data['Id']];
                        });
                    });
                    // mark the record as dirty to be sync
                    record.dirty = true;
                });
                // sync store object with the database
                store.sync();
            }
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/K7U7V/) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/pjBqS/) examples on how to load nested data into a nested model. You will also see how to access the associated data.

I'm not sure why you use `record.ColumnsStore.data.items`, as if record is of `HeaderModel` type, you should really get the columns store via `record.Columns`, and then iterate that store.

Would also help to see what JSON your server returns.

Comment: Thanks @lzhaki  I've added more detail and sample set of json response.  I've looked at the examples you provided, but it doesn't appear to demonstrate how the nested model get loaded into a form.  I have no issue loading the json object into store, but I can't seem to load the data into the form fields I've created.  As for getting the Columns store, both record.ColumnsStore and record.Columns() returns the same thing, so is there a reason why we would use the function getter instead of directly refering to the ColumnsStore in this case?